# Как записать данные в массив JQuery?

Tags: jquery, массивы

```
$(this).find('.container').each(function() {
var text_write = document.getElementById("my_textarea").value;
if (!(text_write).empty) {
    elements.push(text_write);
} else if ((($(this).text()).empty) && ((text_write).empty)) {
    elements.push(" ");
} else if (!(($(this).text()).empty))
    elements.push(($(this).text()));
});
```

Мне нужно, чтобы была запись в массив.

к примеру вот так

```
{"mass_block1":["KRUTO","Random_text"],"mass_block2":["KLASSNO"],"mass_block3":["PRIKOLNO"]}
```

'Random_text' это то , что записано в text_write

он делает за место `Random_text` вставляет пустоту

```
{"mass_block1":["KRUTO"," "],"mass_block2":["KLASSNO"],"mass_block3":["PRIKOLNO"]}
```

Это статичный текст , который есть в блоке

```
 ($(this).text())
```

Это тот текст , которые пользователь вводит в textarea

```
elements.push(text_write);
```

P.S. перетаскиваю элементы из драг в дроп.

```
mass_block1 mass_block2 mass_block3
```

это три дропа

нужно, чтоб к примеру гость перетащил текстарею в определенный дроп к примеру mass_block3 и чтоб он там и записался, а то как бы я не пытался , он записывается у всех тоже

```
{"mass_block1":["KRUTO","Random_text"],"mass_block2":["KLASSNO","Random_text"],"mass_block3":["PRIKOLNO","Random_text"]}
```

так не надо , он должен записать только в тот дроп , куда его положили

Comment: что означает этот код `!(text_write).empty`, на сколько я знаю поля `empty` у строк не существует

Comment: Там у меня должна быть проверка на пустоту. тогда " " ?

Comment: Нужен полный пример кода, а то не понятно что у вас в роли elements?
И как я понял у вас 3 драг&дропа и Вам нужно чтоб вы перетащили текстарею в один из них, сформировался соответсвующий массив?

Comment: Есть три драгена и три дропа . Два драгееа с текстом , который уже есть, а третий с ТЕКСТАРЕЕ. Я ,перетаскиваю ДВА ДРАГЕНА в дропы, беру их текст при помощи this text и формируется массив {"mass_block1":["KRUTO"],"mass_block2":["KLASSNO"],"mass_block3":[""]} , третий драген-иекстарея и поэтому там данные беру по другому и поэтому ,если в третий дроп перетащить драген с текстареей то получится массив , который я в самом низу кинул. Добавится везде, а мне надо, чтоб значение добавилась в массив  именно к тому дропу, к которому он был закинут, в нашем случае это к третьим только , а не ко всем